# bootstrap 5.1 dropdown not working properly with react

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

I am learning react and for styling I am trying to use bootstrap.

I am stuck on using dropdown. I explored almost all stackoverflow posts on the same but unable to resolve. If anyone is aware of the proper solution, please help me out.

my component class :

```
import React from "react";


function ExpenseFilter() {

    return (
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-around">

            <div className="text-light">
                <h4>filter expenses by year</h4>
            </div>

            <div className="dropdown">
                <button className="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    select year
                </button>

                <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <a className="dropdown-item" href="/#">2019</a>
                    <a className="dropdown-item" href="/#">2020</a>
                    <a className="dropdown-item" href="/#">2021</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ExpenseFilter;
```

index.js class :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"; 
import "@popperjs/core"; 
import "bootstrap";



ReactDOM.render(
<App />,document.getElementById('root')
);
```

package.json :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
    "npm": "^7.21.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-popper": "^2.2.5",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  }
```

- no errors on console. dropdown button renders properly but does not shows dropdown options on clicking it
- no errors/warning during npm start as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem with your use of bootstrap5, the correct attribute of button is `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"` instead of `data-toggle="dropdown"`.